# C local and global static variables

Tags: c, global-variables, static-variables

My *understanding* is that a local static variable has "program scope"; that is, once defined it lives until the program terminates. Furthermore, my understanding is that local statics are also accessible outside the current module/C-file they are defined inside of:

```
void doSomething() {
    static int myVar = 5;   // Program scope & accessible to other modules
}
```

My *understanding* is that global static variables also have program scope, but that they are only visible to the current module/C-file:

```
static int myVar = 5;       // Program scope but "module private"
void doSomething() {
    // Whatever here...
}
```

Isn't this a bit backwards? I would have expected it to be the other way around. So I ask: is my understanding above correct? If so, then what is the motivation for local statics to be accessible outside their current module, but not global statics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You messed up all. Static local variable is a place to **hide data from other functions** but retain data for future calls of that function.

Static global variables have

- static storage duration  (Retain data for future call)
- internal linkage (variable is restricted to single file) and
- file scope               (Only in the current file the variable can be referenced)

Static local variables have

- static storage duration
- no linkage
- block scope

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Local Static variables are accessible with in given module.

While Global static variables are accessible with in given C-file.

Answer (score 0):

Local static variable has limited scope to the function only.
As you can see, following code gives compilation error because it tries to access "prox" variable from main even though it is static.

```
int main(void)
{
test();
printf("The PROX is : %d", prox);
}

test()
{
static prox;
prox=prox+5;
printf("INSIDE prox[%d]",prox);
}
```